# How To: 100% Height Table only Scroll tbody

Tags: html, css

is it possible to scroll the content of a 100% height table and not the header using CSS and only showing the scroll bar to the side of the tbody content and not the header row? Thanks!

Comment: You can do it, but it requires fixed width columns. Sgs3 provided two solutions for this.  Otherwise you will need javascript/jquery.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33075195/435605

Answer (score 7):

I hope it's not too late and you are still alive, things have improved a lot since then :)

You can use:

```
table {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "head-fixed" 
  "body-scrollable";
}

thead {
  grid-area: head-fixed;
}

tbody {
  grid-area: body-scrollable;
  overflow: auto;
  height: calc(100vh - 55px);
}
```

Scrollable table (tbody) with 100% height and fixed header on JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gengns/p3fzdc5f/

Comment: This seems to be quite elegant solution. However, the width of the thead columns doesn't match the with of the corresponding td elements. Would I have to apply fixed width to the elements to fix that?

Comment: @dabs thank you for your compliment (simplicity as reliability). Yes, it’s a cool way to scroll `tbody`. Talking about the `width`, you need to fix a min `th:first-of-type, td:first-of-type { min-width: 50px; }` However, you can play with CSS Grid and use a different `grid-template-areas` to make `th` and `td` occupy the same space : ) maybe in this case you would prefer to avoid `table`. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 6):

Tables are tricky business. I guess you want to use them for semantic and fallback purposes, but they're somewhat unflexible.

Luckily some already figured out not one, but 2 good methods of achieving scrollable effects.... in ~2005.

http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/tablescroll.html

They still need extra html markup to make it possible and the second table effectively uses a nested table, but the fallback / plain HTML looks like a normal plain table.

**Method #1**

Outer div with padding, to create a 'field' for the elements. Inner div which makes the inner table scrollable. The `thead` table row is absolutely positioned to make it stay on top of the body, same is done with the footer. Because the inner div is `overflow: auto` and a height defined the rest of the table rows fall inline in the scollable area.

**Method #2**

The outer table is a normal table, header and footer are styled normally. But the tbody of the outer table contains only one row, one column and in it it has another table. This column has a height defined and `overflow: auto` so the able in it (which only has the content) will be scrolled inside it.

Comment: In both cases the dimensions of individual columns is set manually.  Haven't yet seen a way to do this and still let the browser lay out the table.

Comment: @MichaelSlade This is to make the headers line up properly with their respective columns... unfortunately en suprisingly maybe, html tables weren't designed with these mechanics in mind. I guess that in the end if you want a more dynamic layout system in html and use the table structure you're going to have to use some js to sync the header/columns up with each other. I think setting the widths is a small price to pay.

Comment: Just one more thing to point out on method #2, maybe kind of obvious, but you also need to add colspan to the only row of outter/first table to match the columns of second table.

Answer (score 3):

A javascript solution is to use 'floating headers'.  You put the whole table in a div with overflow set, then the JavaScript will clone the table header and put it at the top of the div,  a bit like an Apple interface.

A jQuery example is http://fixedheadertable.com/

Note that this gets very complex if you're doing other things to the table,  such as client-side sorting, filtering,  etc.

Comment: The link results in "Sorry, the page you were looking for in this blog does not exist"

Comment: I've changed the link from http://slackers.se/2009/jquery-floating-header-plugin to an equivalent plugin  http://fixedheadertable.com/. @Shadow Wizard - thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with pure CSS as far as I know (at least not cross browser) but using jQuery plugin it's possible and very simple e.g. [jQuery.FixedTable](http://www.novasoftware.com/Download/jQuery_FixedTable/JQuery_FixedTable.aspx).

Comment: The Link to dotnetoutsource.com is broken

Comment: @Rob thanks for the heads up, so many plugins die so fast... found the plugin I had in mind in other location.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with flex display. No need for hard coded sizes.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/6VWatI?p=preview)'s an example of how to do a fixed header and a scrollable content using in a table. Code:

```
<html style="height: 100%">
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Fixed Header in table</title>
    <!-- Reset browser defaults -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
  </head>
  <body style="height: 100%">
  <table style="display: flex; height: 100%; flex-direction: column">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>HEADER<br/>------------</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="flex: 1; overflow: auto">
        <tr>
          <td>
          <div>
              CONTENT - START<br/>
              <script>
              for (var i=0 ; i<1000 ; ++i) {
                document.write(" Very long content!");
              }
              </script>
              <br/>CONTENT - END
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

For a full [Holy Grail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Grail_(web_design)) implementation (header, footer, nav, side, and content), using flex display, go to [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/swHKE2?p=preview).

Comment: @cryophoenix - Why do you say that? Here's a screencap with the scroll: https://imgur.com/a/06pYIfl

Comment: @cryophoenix - Perhaps you meant that it doesn't scroll horizontally?

Comment: mb i musta screwed something up

Answer (score 0):

Mat that is simple. Here's what you want to do

**CSS:**

```
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }

  html, body{ width: 100%; height: 100%;}
  table{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #aaa;
  }

  tbody{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -display: block;
    background-color: #ccc;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;

  }

  td{
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #eee;
  }


</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: By the way. If you wanna check this code out real quick, you can use jsbin.com

Answer (score -1):

If possible in your scenario, an easy direct alternative would be to put the header in a separate div and the table inside another div with apt height and apply the following properties to the div.

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Comment: I have looked into this but how do I get the container div as 100% the header div as fixed height and the second inner div as fluid height to fill the remaining space? Thanks

Comment: ^^ Can't you have a fixed height for the container div?

Comment: No because its a fluid height design to look like a native program, I can get it working with fixed height but it has to be fluid!

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem getting only the content under the header to both scroll and remain in 100% of the remaining height. Here was my fix:

http://jsfiddle.net/ajkochanowicz/YDjsE/

This will work for simpler use cases.

```
#container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px; /* This can be any height and everything fills in */
  padding-top: 55px;            
}
#something-else {
  height: 55px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-top:-55px;    
}
#overflow {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width:198px;
  overflow-y: auto; 
  height: 100%;   
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for tabular data as the header columns will not stay in-line with the body columns.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case, @AlikElzin-kilaka ?

Comment: @AdamGrant, I'd like the content to reach the end of the page. That's the reason for the 100%.

Answer (score -2):

try this CSS file :

```
table{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #aaa;
  }

  tbody{
     background-color: #CCCCCC;
    display: block;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
  }

  td{
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #eee;
  }

thead {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

works in my firefox.. not tested anywhere else.. :)

Comment: This doesn't work in Firefox.  It leaves the header with a smaller width than the content, in cases where the header titles are longer than content.

Comment: Changing the display attribute on table elements breaks the table structure main purpose, I don't recommend this approach at all.

Comment: this is a fixed height, not 100%

Comment: @fmsf you can go with 'vh' base if you are not targeting old browsers