# How to set a scroll in a table element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table:

```
<table class="list-table">
  <thead><tr><th>header</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>

   <tr><td>Single row of glorious table content</td></tr>  // Repeat me x100

  </tbody>
</table>
```

This table is wrapped in a div to give it a fixed height:

```
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-9" style="top:80px; bottom:20px;">

   <table>
   ...
   </table>

   </div>
```

Now the question: How can I use `overflow:auto` (or equivalent) to have the `tbody` contents scroll if the TR repeats exceed this fixed height?

**Note I want only the `tbody` (or `tr` contents in the `tbody`) to scroll, not the `thead`or its contents **

***EDIT: UPDATE ***
For those interested, I ended up splitting this into two identical tables, then wrapping the table with the `tbody` in a `overflow:auto` and aligning the `thead` separately with a `position:fixed`

Comment: no you cant, you cant make tbody content scroll without changing its display property, which is a bad idea.

Comment: maybe look for a jquery grid plugin

Comment: you can try YUI datatable with scrollable body - http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_fixedscroll.html

Comment: @MoazzamKhan why is it a bad idea?

Comment: @alias51 This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17380697/1725764

Comment: changing tbody display property will get your a scroll but, your table cell widths will mess up, you can try and see. `display:block` and `overflow:auto`

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you a lot

In your html

```
    <table>
<thead><tr><th>header</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr><td>Single row</td></tr>  
   <tr><td>Single row</td></tr>  
   <tr><td>Single row</td></tr>  
   <tr><td>Single row</td></tr>  
   <tr><td>Single row</td></tr>  
   <tr><td>Single row</td></tr>  
   <tr><td>Single row</td></tr>  
   <tr><td>Single row</td></tr>  
   <tr><td>Single row</td></tr>  
   <tr><td>Single row</td></tr>  
   <tr><td>Single row</td></tr>  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And in your CSS

```
table {width:100%; border:1px solid #000000;}
thead {background-color:#000268;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center; position:fixed; top:0px;}
thead th { height:50px;width:1000px; text-align:center;border-width: 1px;border-style: outset;}
tbody {color:#000000;text-align:center; height:150px; overflow: scroll; margin-top:00px;}
tbody td { height:60px; border-width: 1px;border-style: outset;}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6hfX/1029/)

Comment: Body does not align with head

Comment: Also, the head covers some of the body.

Comment: I think the issue here is the height is set by a parent element, which means this approach wont work?

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this:

```
<table class="list-table">
  <thead><tr><th>header</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-9" style="top:80px; bottom:20px; height:400px;overflow-y:auto;">
          <table>
            <tr><td>Single row of glorious table content</td></tr>  // Repeat me x100
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Of course, if you have multiple `td`s, you may have to manually set all their widths to keep them properly aligned.

[Ugly fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g8Kza/)

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in a div.

```
    <table>
       <thead>...</thead>
       <tbody><tr><td>
       <div style = "overflow:auto">
         //table without the header here
       </div>
       </td></tr></tbody>
    </table>
```

If the innertable has no margins or padding or anything of that nature, it should look like part of the original table.

Comment: That would scroll the thead content

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't appear to work. Is it semantically correct to have a div in a table but outside a cell?

Comment: @alias51 the div is in a cell. The table has exactly 1 cell that contains the div

Answer (score 0):

add style for your tbody   there are overflow: auto, overflow-x:scroll, overflow-y:scroll

user whatever suits you best.
if you use tbody a fixed height  only tbody will scroll not the thead.

Comment: @Biswajit Did you ever do it before?