# Scrollable Table Tbody

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table with dynamically generated data. Because of space limitation, I need to be able to make the the tbody scrollable.

My table looks like this:

```
<table>
    <thead> <! -- This thead needs to stay in a fixed position-->
        <tr>
               <th></th>
               <th></th>
        </tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody> <! -- This tbody needs to stay in a fixed position-->
     <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tbody> <! -- This tbody needs to scroll -->
     <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

I've tried using css, but have been unsuccessful:

```
table tbody:nth-child(2) {
height:500px;
max-height:500px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

My ideal solution is simple css. Any suggestions? Also, why does setting a height on a tbody not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the `tbody` scrollable by doing the below:

```
tbody { 
    display: block; /* mandatory because scroll only works on block elements */
}

tbody:nth-child(3) {
    height: 75px;       /* Just for the demo          */
    overflow-y: auto;    /* Trigger vertical scroll    */
    width: 100px;       /* Just for the demo          */ 
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/guT8P/) | [**Demo with Class Name**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/guT8P/7/)

**Note:** If you wish you can either target the `tbody` as mentioned in the above sample or much better would be assigning it a scrollable class and doing as below:

```
tbody.scrollable {
    height: 75px;       /* Just for the demo          */
    overflow-y: auto;    /* Trigger vertical scroll    */
    width: 100px;       /* Just for the demo          */ 
}
```

**Base Idea:** Base Idea is taken from Hashem's answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody).

**Update:** The `tbody:nth-child(2)` didn't work because that selector applies the style to the 2nd child element which is also a `tbody`. In our case, it worked but it didn't have any effect because the 2nd child within the table was the first `tbody` (after the `thead`) and it had lesser contents which made the scrollbar unnecessary. When we made it to `nth-child(3)`, it worked because the 2nd `tbody` is actually the 3rd child element and had enough contents to exceed the set height and thereby triggered the scrollbar to come.

Have a look at this [**sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/th7sj/) for reference. We can see that the style is not applied for the 1st element in the 2nd `div` and the 2nd element in the 1st `div` because both of them are not `p` tags (even though the CSS rule was same for both divs).

Comment: Harry, this works in your demo, but when I update it with my table, this doe not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/guT8P/5/

Comment: Ah, you took the example that I was updating at the wrong time. For that sample which uses `tbody.second`, you need to assign the `class='second'` to the corresponding `tbody` like `<tbody class='second'>`. Or better still a semantical and re-usable class name would be `scrollable`.

Comment: I cant believe I did that, haha I thought .second was some new selector. duh

Comment: Happens to the best of us too mate. By the way, have a look at [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody) for some alternates.

Comment: The `nth-child` didn't work probably because both of us overlooked the fact that the `tbody` that we were looking to scroll is actually the 3rd child within the table and not the 2nd. Refer [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/th7sj/) and see that 1st child doesn't get the style because it is not a `p` element (it is a `h1`).

Comment: This does not work once you don't use 'a' as header and footer: once you set display: block on tbody/thead the column widths don't match up anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try below approach **simple easy to implement**

below is the jsfiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/v2t2k8ke/2/

HTML:

```
<table border='1' id='tbl_cnt'>
<thead><tr></tr></thead><tbody></tbody>
```

CSS:

```
 #tbl_cnt{
 border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;word-break:break-all;
 }
 #tbl_cnt thead, #tbl_cnt tbody{
 display: block;
 }
 #tbl_cnt thead tr{
 background-color: #8C8787; text-align: center;width:100%;display:block;
 }
 #tbl_cnt tbody {
 height: 100px;overflow-y: auto;overflow-x: hidden;
 }
```

Jquery:

```
 var data = [
    {
    "status":"moving","vehno":"tr544","loc":"bng","dri":"ttt"
    }, {
    "status":"stop","vehno":"tr54","loc":"che", "dri":"ttt"
    },{    "status":"idle","vehno":"yy5499999999999994","loc":"bng","dri":"ttt"
    },{
    "status":"moving","vehno":"tr544","loc":"bng", "dri":"ttt"
    }, {
    "status":"stop","vehno":"tr54","loc":"che","dri":"ttt"
    },{
    "status":"idle","vehno":"yy544","loc":"bng","dri":"ttt"
    }
    ];
   var sth = '';
   $.each(data[0], function (key, value) {
     sth += '<td>' + key + '</td>';
   });
   var stb = '';        
   $.each(data, function (key, value) {
       stb += '<tr>';
       $.each(value, function (key, value) {
       stb += '<td>' + value + '</td>';
       });
       stb += '</tr>';
    });
      $('#tbl_cnt thead tr').append(sth);
      $('#tbl_cnt tbody').append(stb);
      setTimeout(function () {
      var col_cnt=0 
      $.each(data[0], function (key, value) {col_cnt++;});    
      $('#tbl_cnt thead tr').css('width', ($("#tbl_cnt tbody") [0].scrollWidth)+ 'px');
      $('#tbl_cnt thead tr td,#tbl_cnt tbody tr td').css('width',  ($('#tbl_cnt thead tr ').width()/Number(col_cnt)) + 'px');}, 100)
```