# make position of table heading fixed even after scrolling

Tags: php, jquery, css, scrollbar

I have a table with a vertical scroll bar

```
<div id="div_data" style="top: 7px;">
<table id="data" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <thead>
              <tr class="fix"><td class="newClass"> <div> Algebra </div></td>
                   <td class="newClass"><div> Geometry</div></td>
                   <td class="newClass"><div> Theorems</div></td> 
                   <td class="newClass"><div> Comment</div></td>
                   </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody style="overflow:auto; height:100px;">
            ......................
            </tbody>

    </table>
        <table id="header-fixed" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"></table> 
    </div>
```

When I scroll the `#data table`, I need to make the table heading elements to be fixed without scrolling.For that I have done the following jquery code:

```
var tableOffset = $("#data").offset().top;
var $header = $("#data > thead").clone();
var $fixedHeader = $("#header-fixed").append($header);  
    $("#div_data").scroll(function(){ 
        $('#div_row_headers').scrollTop($('#div_data').scrollTop()); 
         var offset = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (offset >= tableOffset && $fixedHeader.is(":hidden")) {
            $fixedHeader.show();
        }
        else if (offset < tableOffset) {
            $fixedHeader.hide();
        } 
    });
```

The content inside the  element of the first table is cloned inside the second table,but the position of the `#header-fixed` table is not on the heading region of the first table.It is coming in the middle of the table.I just want to superimpose it on the position of the  elements in the
`#data table`.My css is below:

```
#header-fixed { 
position: fixed; 
display:none;
background-color:white;
}
table#header-fixed tr td {
    width: 155px;
}       
table#header-fixed tr td div {
    width: 155px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**EDIT:** When I scroll the windows scroll bar,the new table is fixed,I need to scroll the table,when I scroll the window scroll bar

Comment: easiest solution I have used. http://www.fixedheadertable.com/

Comment: @Binary101010 thanks,I need it like that plugin,But without plugins,can I do??I dont want plugins

Comment: sorry. I do not know exactly how I would write it myself. I suggest using a lightweight plugin unless you really need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to do is that wrap your table body using tbody tag. And apply following css to that tag.

```
 tbody {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;        
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody