# First <th> gets way too wide while making a scrollable table

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="scrollable">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="nothing_here">Nothing here</th>
                <th>Tora Gargano</th>
                <th>Emory Beck</th>
                <th>Jane Doe</th>
                <th>Yoshiko Beekman</th>
                <th>Treasa Norris</th>
                <th>Jane Doe</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Actions</th>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Status</th>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>Done</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>Done</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Actions</th>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Status</th>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>Done</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>Done</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The names in the `thead` element doesn't align properly with the values below. The first child of `th` element covers up all the space available.

Here is a link to jsfiddle of my problem http://jsfiddle.net/zLc48uga/ Any ideas?

Comment: http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML table with 100% width, with vertical scroll inside tbody](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody)

Comment: Changing display to table-cell or table-row-group doesn't work because I need vertical scrolling. With table-cell or table-cell-group, it ignores the height and overflow property

Answer (score 2):

If you remove "display:block" from your css all of them line up just fine. Is that what you mean? The table needs to be display:table-cell, otherwise the heads can't line up with the data.

***Edit***

Sorry for the above, I misunderstood. Add display block to your thead too.

```
.scrollable thead {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: But then I won't be able to make it scrollable

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem involves making the `thead` element a `block` element.

To achieve this, you need to apply the following CSS:

```
.scrollable thead {
    display: block;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/pwee167/zLc48uga/2/

Comment: But the headings doesnt align with the data

Answer (score 0):

I think what you tried to do is setting the header fixed, and make the body scrollable.

There is a few ways to do that, but there isn't a good way to do it. 
One way, cross-browser, could be using two different tables: one for your head and the other for your body, and place your body table inside a fixed height div.

For example:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th class="nothing_here">Nothing here</th>
            <th>Tora Gargano</th>
            <th>Emory Beck</th>
            <th>Jane Doe</th>
            <th>Yoshiko Beekman</th>
            <th>Treasa Norris</th>
            <th>Jane Doe</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="scrollable">
       <table>
         <tr>
             <th>Actions</th>
             <td>blah</td>
             <td>blah</td>
             <td>blah</td>
             <td>blah</td>
             <td>blah</td>
             <td>blah</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <th>Actions</th>
             <td>blah</td>
             <td>blah</td>
             <td>blah</td>
             <td>blah</td>
             <td>blah</td>
             <td>blah</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <th>Actions</th>
             <td>blah</td>
             <td>blah</td>
             <td>blah</td>
             <td>blah</td>
             <td>blah</td>
             <td>blah</td>
         </tr>
       </table>
    </div>
```

You can find a demo for that case here: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/w7Mm8/117/)

I recommend you to use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/), it's a good and simple solution using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to break that table apart to add scrolling this is how you can do it:

```css
html {
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
.scrollable thead tr {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.scrollable thead th {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
.scrollable tbody {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.scrollable tbody td, .scrollable tbody th {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="nothing_here">Nothing here</th>
                <th>Tora Gargano</th>
                <th>Emory Beck</th>
                <th>Jane Doe</th>
                <th>Yoshiko Beekman</th>
                <th>Treasa Norris</th>
                <th>Jane Doe</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Actions</th>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Status</th>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>Done</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>Done</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Actions</th>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Status</th>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>Done</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>Done</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Actions</th>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Status</th>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>Done</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>Done</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Actions</th>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
                <td>blah</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Status</th>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>Done</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
                <td>Done</td>
                <td>Pending</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```