# Scrollable tbody issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table, datatables

: )

I know this question has been asked a lot, but I tried many solutions and just couldn't make it work properly.

I need to make the tbody of my table scrollable with fixed headers.

To start my table is built dynamically and is very large. 19 columns and about 800 rows.

**First I worked with the jquery datatables plugin.
After the table is in the container:**

```
var tbl = createFilter('readDataTbl', '', condition);
    $('#tableDiv').empty().append(tbl);

    $('#readDataTbl').dataTable({
        "scrollY": "200px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging": false
    });
```

but that creates a scroll in x and the headers are frozen like that:

[image]

**Then I tried a css solution as follows:**

```
 <style>
        table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
thead {
    text-align:left;
    display: table;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
thead tr {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}
tbody {
    display: block;
    height: 120px;
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
tbody tr {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
tbody tr {
    height: 18px;
}
tbody td {
    padding:1px 8px;
}
th, td {
    width: 25%;
}

tr:after{   /* IE8 fix */
    content: ".";
    margin-left: -3px; /* to hide the content above tr */ /* not necessary if you are ok with 1px gap */
    visibility: hidden;
}
     </style>
```

But that just creates a mess in the tbody like that:

[image]

Then I tried thie method from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody)
adjusting the THs width after:
css:

```
<style>
        thead, tbody { display: block; }

        tbody {
            height: 100px;       /* Just for the demo          */
            overflow-y: auto;    /* Trigger vertical scroll    */
            overflow-x: hidden;  /* Hide the horizontal scroll */
        }
     </style>
```

js:

```
var tbl = createFilter('readDataTbl', '', condition);
    $('#tableDiv').empty().append(tbl);

    var $table = $('table');
    var $bodyCells = $table.find('tbody tr:first').children();
    

    // Get the tbody columns width array
    var colWidth = $bodyCells.map(function () {
        return $(this).width();
    }).get();

    // Set the width of thead columns
    $table.find('thead tr').children().each(function (i, v) {
        $(v).width(colWidth[i]);
    });
```

And then I noticed the THs long text made them bigger like that:

[image]

what could help me achieve my goal?
Thought about inserting divs inside THs but not sure about it..

Thanks! : ]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of flex-box layout. It certainly won't work on safari though. All other major browsers render it perfectly.

/* CSS */

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.table {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.table .tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.table .tr .td, .table .tr .th {
    flex: 1;
}

.table .thead {
    padding-right: 17px;
    /* this padding accounts for the width of the scroll bar
     * you could compute the default scrollbar width for any browser and set this padding accordingly
     * else the headers and records will be misaligned by that margin. */
}

.table .viewport {
    height: 640px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

/* HTML */

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ftable.css" />
    <title>Flex tables</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="table">
    <div class="thead">
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="th">Column 1</div>
            <div class="th">Column 2</div>
            <div class="th">Column 3</div>
            <div class="th">Column 4</div>
            <div class="th">Column 5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="viewport tbody">
        <div class="canvas">
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">Value 1</div>
                <div class="td">Value 2</div>
                <div class="td">Value 3</div>
                <div class="td">Value 4</div>
                <div class="td">Value 5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I made one sample, with two or three lines of javascript you could make it work perfectly fine, atleast on most of the major browsers. I haven't been around stack for a few years. So bear with me in my editing.

Comment: I made a mistake while copying the snippet. Check for the last block in the css part. Its take care of.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this perfectly without some javascript. The best way to accomplish this would be to use a clone of the header, prepend it to the element, apply a fixed position on it and hide the original. Hope this helps. You might also need to bind each column width to the width of the original.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use bootstrap css and some table styles. You can adjust the **th** height and width for better results. Also you must calculate the percentage width of `tbody td, thead th {` ie if you have 19 columns then 100/19 which is around 5%. So your column width will be very less and you will need to increase the height for `thead th {`

```css
        table {
          width: 100%;
        }
        thead,
        tbody,
        tr,
        td,
        th {
          display: block;
        }
        tr:after {
          content: ' ';
          display: block;
          visibility: hidden;
          clear: both;
        }
        thead th {
          height: 50px;
          /*text-align: left;*/
        }
        tbody {
          height: 120px;
          overflow-y: auto;
        }
        thead {
          /* fallback */
        }
        tbody td,
        thead th {
          width: 19.2%;
          float: left;
        }
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Make fg jfdg jfgj fgjfg jfgj fgj fgj g jfgj fgj dfgj fgjfg</th>
      <th>Model</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Fordfghdfg jfdgjfdgj fgj fdgj fgjfgj df</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ok assume anyways you could achieve this for desktop version what would be the case for mobile haha ha ha ha

Comment: basically if all colums are mandate then we have to change it to tab view rather than hiding columns :  abhiklpm