# How to add scrollbars using bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this html Code taken from http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Simple Tables</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="table-responsive"> 
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Row</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Biography</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Carter</td>
                    <td>johncarter@mail.com</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Peter</td>
                    <td>Parker</td>
                    <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
                    <td>Vestibulum consectetur scelerisque lacus, ac fermentum lorem convallis sed. Nam odio tortor, dictum quis malesuada at, pellentesque.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Rambo</td>
                    <td>johnrambo@mail.com</td>
                    <td>Integer pulvinar leo id risus pellentesque vestibulum. Sed diam libero, sodales eget sapien vel, porttitor bibendum enim.</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I add a scroll bar (up-down) & (left-right) using bootstrap without affecting the width of the web page? Like I want it to have a fixed column(4) and row(5) to display when I add another row and columns to the table. If I add another  to the table, my webpage seems to extend. like the code I post above, like it must have a fixed height and width to the web page. Is there any possible way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this css

```
thead, tbody { display: block; }
tbody {
    height: 100px;       /* Just for the demo          */
    overflow-y: auto;    /* Trigger vertical scroll    */
    overflow-x: hidden;  /* Hide the horizontal scroll */
}
```

Thanks to [hashem-qolami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1725764/hashem-qolami)

For more information [Read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody)

Comment: Thanks sir it work! :) , but will it affect this format if this code is access in mobile.?

Comment: yes it works in mobile view also.....Happy to help...

Comment: thank you. :)  uhm do I add another <meta> to make this code mobile friendly and it will not affect its current format?

Comment: ok sir thank you so much for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

Set `max-height` and `max-width` CSS properties to show your desired number of `Rows` and `Columns` and set `overflow-y:scroll;` and `overflow-x:scroll;`. Like

```
 .table-responsive{
    max-height: 250px;
    max-width: 100px;
    overflow-y:scroll; 
    overflow-x:scroll; 
 }
```

Comment: this one works also sir, thank you for effort. :)