# Scroll function make left contraction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I'm using following script for Fixed my menu when Scroll the page.

```
var num = 5;
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('.scroll').css({'position':'fixed', 'top':'0px'});
    } else {
        $('.scroll').css({'position':'', 'top':''});
    }
});
```

I'm using this script for table. See [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qowzuo8m/).
When Scroll Down, that title is going contraction to left left side.

Why It's happening and How I can fix?
It should support major browsers(not IE).

Comment: It's because you haven't set left which you need to, as the default is 0 (left border).

Comment: @LShetty I didn't get you

Comment: You can see this, to make scrolling only for table body

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody

Answer (score 1):

When you set `position: fixed` the left prop seems to be set to 0. Hence, the headers were moving to the left corner. You may have to play with `display` and `width` props to do what you're after. Also note that adding/removing a class is better than setting inline styles via `.css()`. Look at the following demo and adapt the code accordingly to suit your needs.

```js
var num = 5;
$(document).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > num) {
  $('.scroll').addClass("scrolled");
    } else {
        $('.scroll').removeClass("scrolled");
    }
});
```

```css
.scroll { width: 100%; }
.scroll th { width: 49% }
.scrolled { position: fixed; top: 0; }
.scrolled th { display: inline-block; width: 47.5% }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr class="scroll">
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" width="20%">0</td>
            <td align="center" width="20%">1</td>
        </tr>
        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

There may be other ways of doing it, but this is what I could quickly think of :)

Comment: It's ok for just 2 fields. If I have more than 5 fields with different width means? Make Sense.

Comment: Post a fiddle with the complete table.