# set height of div and make vertical scroll on fixed element

Tags: css

i set up a fiddle , and was hoping there was a way to get this to scroll , but haven't been able to figure it out

http://jsfiddle.net/sq181h3h/3/

I have tried both of these , but nothing working

```
#league_chat {
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
#league_chat {
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Comment: If you want to just divide the info and the headers for the scroller, here: http://jsfiddle.net/sq181h3h/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to apply the scroll to the tbody directly then I believe this has been answered previously:

[HTML table with 100% width, with vertical scroll inside tbody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody#17380697)

Answer (score 0):

I think its because it's a `table`.  You should give your table a wrapping div then set your height, width, and overflow properties on it.

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sq181h3h/5/).

Comment: any possible way to just get the tbody to scroll ?

Comment: Ya sure. In your case you can just set the `<caption>` to `position:fixed;`. See this updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sq181h3h/7/). I gave it a few other styles to render better

Comment: I could not find a way with CSS to do this , so i used jQuery to wrap the tbody with a div class and set that to height and overflow