# Scrollable table for e-mails (without a div)

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

Is it possible to create a table with a content scrollable vertically (the table is 600x600)? The only way I know is with using a div which is not possible for e-mails' purposes.

Comment: [This has been asked earlier on StackOverflow.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve above by using css.By mentioning this you can achieve the result overflow-Y:scroll (for verticle scroll bar)

```css
table{
  overflow-Y:scroll;
  height:600px;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th>EMail</th>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Please be aware this is not a universal solution as some clients do not recognize overflow nor even recognize stylesheets.  Others still (usually webmail) will not allow a scroll due to security issue with the stabilization of the HTML/CSS on their page.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to generate dynamic tables from java code , adding this line of code made the table scrollable inside the email body in Outlook email client.

Embedded Html like so : `<div  style= 'width:800px; height:400px; overflow:scroll; position:relative;'>`

java code looks like :

```
body.append("<div  style= 'width:800px; height:400px; overflow:scroll; position:relative;'>");
body.append("<table border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0'>");
```