# how to add a scrollbar inside a table with fixed header?

Tags: html, css

Can somebody help me to adjust the scrollbar inside the table with a fixed header?

```css
table a:link {
 color: #666;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration:none;
}
table a:visited {
 color: #999999;
 font-weight:bold;
 text-decoration:none;
}
table a:active,
table a:hover {
 color: #bd5a35;
 text-decoration:underline;
}
table {
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color:#666;
 font-size:12px;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
 background:#eaebec;
 margin:20px;
 border:#ccc 1px solid;

 -moz-border-radius:3px;
 -webkit-border-radius:3px;
 border-radius:3px;

 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
}
table th {
 padding:21px 25px 22px 25px;
 border-top:1px solid #fafafa;
 border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;

 background: #ededed;
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ededed), to(#ebebeb));
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ededed,  #ebebeb);
}
table th:first-child {
 text-align: left;
 padding-left:20px;
}
table tr:first-child th:first-child {
 -moz-border-radius-topleft:3px;
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius:3px;
 border-top-left-radius:3px;
}
table tr:first-child th:last-child {
 -moz-border-radius-topright:3px;
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius:3px;
 border-top-right-radius:3px;
}
table tr {
 text-align: center;
 padding-left:20px;
}
table td:first-child {
 text-align: left;
 padding-left:20px;
 border-left: 0;
}
table td {
 padding:18px;
 border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
 border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
 border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;

 background: #fafafa;
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fbfbfb), to(#fafafa));
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fbfbfb,  #fafafa);
}
table tr.even td {
 background: #f6f6f6;
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f8f8f8), to(#f6f6f6));
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f8f8f8,  #f6f6f6);
}
table tr:last-child td {
 border-bottom:0;
}
table tr:last-child td:first-child {
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:3px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
}
table tr:last-child td:last-child {
 -moz-border-radius-bottomright:3px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
}
table tr:hover td {
 background: #f2f2f2;
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f2f2f2), to(#f0f0f0));
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f2f2f2,  #f0f0f0); 
}
```

```html
<div class="tablecontainer">
  <div class="table" >
    <table cellspacing='0'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Tutor Name </th>
          <th>Tutor NRIC</th>
         
          <th>Tutor Email</th>
          <th>Tutor qualification</th>
        </tr>
        
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Jane</td> 
          <td>1234567</td>
          <td>Jane@gmail.com</td>
          <td>Diploma</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>John</td>
           <td>1234567</td>
          <td>jphn@gmail.com</td>
          <td>Diploma</td>
        </tr>
          
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Usually you get better results if you post what you tried. Something about it being less of a handout and more of a "you almost had it, it's this." Regardless, your question is a little odd. Is all you want a fixed header with the rest of the table scrolling? If that's the case, [dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17067294/5116879)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: here is what i tried .....haha

Comment: would u be able to help me with it ? thank you ^^

Comment: Check your link please. it's blank JSFiddle link.

Comment: http://codepen.io/ginginhui/pen/gPmaNy

Answer (score 2):

Your `tbody` must have a height and an overflow rule to activate the scrollbar. Meanwhile your `thead` must be positioned

```
.wrap-scroll thead {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.wrap-scroll {
   height: 106px;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

See my [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/obZwZw) for it