# Scrollable tbody doesn't occupy all available width

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table, width

I have a table that contains a lot of rows (1000+). Structure is really simple, here is a simplified example with only one row.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>column 1</th>
            <th>column 2</th>
            <th>column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need column names to be fixed, so I made tbody scrollable. I added these CSS rules

```
tbody {
    display: block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: none;
    max-height: 150px;
}
```

Here is a full [JSfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ea2gfLvk/)

There are 2 problems.

1. `<tbody>` doesn't occupy all the width. I tried with `width: 100%;` but it doesn't work. `display: block;` seems to prevent normal width behaviour but I need it for the scroll. How can I do it occupy all the available space? It's fine even if only 1 column get all the remaining space
2. `<thead>` and `<tbody>` column width is different. At the moment I use a jQuery piece of code to set headers width like other rows, this is fine but I wonder if a better solution is possible.

Answer (score 4):

add this to css

```
thead,
tbody tr {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed; /* even columns width , fix width of table too*/
```

}

Comment: U saved my day bro!

Comment: Yeah, this worked, but any idea if the Scroll bar can be made outside?
A small scroll is spoiling the columns layout , I had to remove the borders.

Answer (score 2):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17380697/4334348) can help: it gives all the possible solutions, both pure css and with jquery.

This a working solution in pure css where also `<tbody>` and `<thead>` have the same width:

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
   
    
    text-align: left;
    
     display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

thead {
    border: 1px solid grey;
        /* head takes the height it requires, 
    and it's not scaled when table is resized */
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

tbody {
   
  
    max-height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
        /* body takes all the remaining available space */
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}






table tbody tr {
    width: 100%;
}
table thead,
table tbody tr {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
/* decorations */
.table-container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0.3em;
}
table {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
table td, table th {
    padding: 0.3em;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
table th {
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

td{
    word-wrap:break-word
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>column 1</th>
            <th>column 2</th>
            <th>column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1akeuntveiuyrtiueyctiuyetiuyenaiuc</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value sifcaiuerycnpiuaerypintcer2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT - Alternative solution**: If you remove `display:block;` from `<tbody>`, your code works.

```
tbody {

overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: none;
max-height: 150px;
border: 1px solid grey;
width: 100%
}
```

Comment: it works but make columns `width` fixed (ok it's a percentage but it's not based on contents)

Comment: @Naigel I have modified my answer to make the cells contain the whole text in multiple lines

Comment: @Naigel I have also added a correction for your code to work

Comment: Your first soultion was better, I try to make width somehow adaptable (a mix of `width` in percentage and a `min-width` in px)

Comment: Great answer, but please add some more inline documentation to your css ;)

Comment: If you removed `display: block;` the table will not be scrollable.

Answer (score 1):

Define  to this css

```
tbody > tr , thead > tr{display:table;width:100%;}
tbody, thead{display: block;}
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}

thead {
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
tbody > tr , thead > tr{display:table;width:100%;}
tbody, thead{display: block;}
tbody {
    
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: none;
    max-height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 100%
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>column 1</th>
            <th>column 2</th>
            <th>column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: the problem here is that columns are not alligned when text length is different, but I can try to add some `width` percentage combined with `min-width` absolute value