# How to apply width 100% with scroll able table body

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement the table body scrollable.  I am able to successfully did it but now I am facing issue with width 100%

Please check this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Ratan_Paul/stpgd6x6/

```html
<table>
<thead style="display:block;">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody style="max-height: 50px;display: block;overflow-y:auto;">
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Can't I apply the width to thead and tbody ? any solution so I can use the scroll as well as set the width to 100%

Comment: why this question got down vote?

Comment: Check out this http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/CrSpu/558/

Comment: @AbhishekPandey thanks, man but if try to use your code in jsfiddle my last column is not properly alligned  https://jsfiddle.net/Ratan_Paul/stpgd6x6/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to clear a few styles that initially come with tables as well as set a width of 33% since you're using 3 column headers (100%/3)

See below:

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

thead, tbody, tr, td, th { display: block; }

tr:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
}

thead th { 
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
}

tbody {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

thead {
    /* fallback */
    width: 97%;
    /* minus scroll bar width */
    width: calc(100% - 17px);
}

tbody { border-top: 2px solid black; }

tbody td, thead th {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
}

tbody td:last-child, thead th:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

More detailed answer can be found here: [HTML table with 100% width, with vertical scroll inside tbody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody)

Comment: check the last column and its values not aligned properly

Comment: @Ratan Please see it now

Comment: Atom, sorry but the scrollable is not present now

Comment: @Ratan Whoops! Corrected now!

Answer (score 5):

There is a much simpler CSS solution to this. Instead of worrying about the widths and scroll of elements, wrap the table with a container div and use the style `position: sticky` to the `th` elements. Example snippet below -

```css
.table-container {
  max-height: 160px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
}

td, th {
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this Code. I think this is best for you**

```css
table{
  width:100%;
}
tbody{
  width:100% !important;
  max-height: 50px;
  display: block;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
thead{
  min-width:100% !important;
}
thead tr{
  width:calc(100% - 17px) !important;
  display:inline-block;
}
tbody tr{
  width:100% !important;
  display:inline-block;
}
th, td{
  width:30% !important;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks man, this looks great, if you notice last column country is not properly aligned with its values

Comment: thanks man, i already able to fix this issue by Adam's code. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make the table scrollable and set it's height, you only have to work with the table itself.

Remove all styling on your table, and add this css:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 80px;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}
```

See this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/stpgd6x6/3/

Comment: I want to make header fixed and body scrollable