# Table with horizontal and vertical scroll with fixed header

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-tables

I do have a table with horizontal and vertical scroll with a fixed header with elements taking as much as space it needs. I am working with React. It would be awesome if there is a react based solution too if CSS alone cannot solve it.

### Note:

- I did try other solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574516/how-to-apply-width-100-with-scroll-able-table-body) but it is not what I'm looking for
- It would be better if td can have min-width set on them too
- The header shows menu when it is clicked for sorting and filtering

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21168521/9540991)?

Comment: I don't know about React, but there is a nice and complete jQuery plugin to do so:
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_xy.html

Comment: React based solution would be nice since I cant include jQuery

Comment: I did find a similar plugin in react react-sticky-table but the problem was the children could not connect to redux-store https://github.com/henrybuilt/react-sticky-table/issues/37

Comment: any codesandbox of what you have tried ? it will be helpful to the community to assist you :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a simple CSS solution to fix rows(headers) and columns in a table.

```
th {
  position: sticky:
  top: 0;
}
```

The above snippet will fix the header to the top. Then it's just a matter of adding a simple overflow to the parent container of the table. You can find a simple example below -

```css
.table-container {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 160px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Head 1</th>
        <th>Head 2</th>
        <th>Head 3</th>
        <th>Head 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It does work. It was silly of me not think this. In addition to the above code I just needed to add ``` width: 100%;```

Comment: this looks better than the rest I tried but this is not retaining the borders :(

Comment: here it is @dbigpot, https://jsfiddle.net/0dzkvutp/2/

Comment: Why it is not returning border @dpigpot

Comment: The solution works but why is the table header changing it's height when scrolling? How to prevent that?