# Make tablebody scrollable into table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this table:
And I like to make the table body scrollable so that I don't have to scroll the page, but that I can scroll inside the tablebody.

```js
function sortTable(table, col, reverse) {
    var tb = table.tBodies[0], // use `<tbody>` to ignore `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` rows
        tr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tb.rows, 0), // put rows into array
        i;
    reverse = -((+reverse) || -1);
    tr = tr.sort(function (a, b) { // sort rows
        return reverse // `-1 *` if want opposite order
            * (a.cells[col].textContent.trim() // using `.textContent.trim()` for test
                .localeCompare(b.cells[col].textContent.trim())
               );
    });
    for(i = 0; i < tr.length; ++i) tb.appendChild(tr[i]); // append each row in order
}

function makeSortable(table) {
    var th = table.tHead, i;
    th && (th = th.rows[0]) && (th = th.cells);
    if (th) i = th.length;
    else return; // if no `<thead>` then do nothing
    while (--i >= 0) (function (i) {
        var dir = 1;
        th[i].addEventListener('click', function () {sortTable(table, i, (dir = 1 - dir))});
    }(i));
}

function makeAllSortable(parent) {
    parent = parent || document.body;
    var t = parent.getElementsByTagName('table'), i = t.length;
    while (--i >= 0) makeSortable(t[i]);
}

window.onload = function () {makeAllSortable();};
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 80%;
 margin: auto;
    background: #fff;
 text-align: center;
}
td, th {
    padding: 0.75em 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
}
td.err {
 background-color: #e992b9;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 0.75em;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 1;
}
th {
    background-color: #7fb030;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
 text-align: center;
}

tbody th {
 background-color: #7fb030;
 text-align: center;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(2n-1) {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    transition: all .125s ease-in-out;
}
.overzicht tr:hover {
    background-color: rgba(129,208,177,.3);
}
```

```html
<table class="overzicht scroll" id="table" style="width: 80%;"> 
    <thead>
    <tr style="cursor: hand;">
    <th style="width: 10%;">Allemaal</th>
    <th style="width: 18%;">Datum</th>
    <th style="width: 16%;" class="left">Naam</th>
    <th style="width: 10%;" class="left">Bedrijf</th>
    <th style="width: 22%;" class="left">Email</th>
    <th style="width: 14%;" class="left">SMS</th>
    <th style="width: 10%;">Geblokkeerd</th>
    </tr>
    </thead><tbody>
  
   <tr class="cus1">
   <form method="post"></form><td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="alles">
       <option value="Ja" selected="">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee">Nee</option>
  
      <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="39">
      <input type="hidden" name="A" value="0">
      <p style="display:none;">0</p>
     </td>
    
    <td style="width: 18%;">
     19-01-2017  10:28  
    </td>
    <td style="width: 16%;" class="left">
     Testpersoon 
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;" class="left">
     test
    </td>
    <td style="width: 22%;" class="left">
     jbn@ti.nl
    </td>
    <td style="width: 14%;" class="left">
     
    </td>
    <form method="post"></form><td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="geblokkeerd">
       <option value="Ja" selected="">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="IDS" value="39">
      <input type="hidden" name="B" value="1">
      <p style="display:none;">1</p>
     </td></tr>
  
   <tr class="cus1">
   <td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="alles">
       <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee" selected="">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="38">
      <input type="hidden" name="A" value="0">
      <p style="display:none;">0</p>
     </td>
    
    <td style="width: 18%;">
     19-01-2017  10:28  
    </td>
    <td style="width: 16%;" class="left">
     Testpersoon 
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;" class="left">
     test
    </td>
    <td style="width: 22%;" class="left">
     jban@ti.nl
    </td>
    <td style="width: 14%;" class="left">
     
    </td>
    <form method="post"></form><td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="geblokkeerd">
       <option value="Ja" selected="">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="IDS" value="38">
      <input type="hidden" name="B" value="1">
      <p style="display:none;">1</p>
     </td></tr>
  
   <tr class="cus1">
   <td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="alles">
       <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee" selected="">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="36">
      <input type="hidden" name="A" value="0">
      <p style="display:none;">0</p>
     </td>
    
    <td style="width: 18%;">
     19-01-2017  10:28  
    </td>
    <td style="width: 16%;" class="left">
     Testpersoon 
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;" class="left">
     test
    </td>
    <td style="width: 22%;" class="left">
     jboan@tri.nl
    </td>
    <td style="width: 14%;" class="left">
     
    </td>
    <form method="post"></form><td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="geblokkeerd">
       <option value="Ja" selected="">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="IDS" value="36">
      <input type="hidden" name="B" value="1">
      <p style="display:none;">1</p>
     </td></tr>
  
   <tr class="cus1">
   <td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="alles">
       <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee" selected="">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="37">
      <input type="hidden" name="A" value="0">
      <p style="display:none;">0</p>
     </td>
    
    <td style="width: 18%;">
     19-01-2017  10:28  
    </td>
    <td style="width: 16%;" class="left">
     Testpersoon 
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;" class="left">
     test
    </td>
    <td style="width: 22%;" class="left">
     jboan@twi.nl
    </td>
    <td style="width: 14%;" class="left">
     
    </td>
    <form method="post"></form><td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="geblokkeerd">
       <option value="Ja" selected="">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="IDS" value="37">
      <input type="hidden" name="B" value="1">
      <p style="display:none;">1</p>
     </td></tr>
  
   <tr class="cus1">
   <td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="alles">
       <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee" selected="">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="48">
      <input type="hidden" name="A" value="0">
      <p style="display:none;">0</p>
     </td>
    
    <td style="width: 18%;">
     19-01-2017  10:28  
    </td>
    <td style="width: 16%;" class="left">
     Testpersoon 
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;" class="left">
     test
    </td>
    <td style="width: 22%;" class="left">
     fdn@tifdsd.nl
    </td>
    <td style="width: 14%;" class="left">
     
    </td>
    <form method="post"></form><td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="geblokkeerd">
       <option value="Ja" selected="">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="IDS" value="48">
      <input type="hidden" name="B" value="1">
      <p style="display:none;">1</p>
     </td></tr>
  
   <tr class="cus1">
   <td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="alles">
       <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee" selected="">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="50">
      <input type="hidden" name="A" value="0">
      <p style="display:none;">0</p>
     </td>
    
    <td style="width: 18%;">
     19-01-2017  10:28  
    </td>
    <td style="width: 16%;" class="left">
     Testpersoon 
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;" class="left">
     test
    </td>
    <td style="width: 22%;" class="left">
     fdn@tisdrd.nl
    </td>
    <td style="width: 14%;" class="left">
     
    </td>
    <form method="post"></form><td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="geblokkeerd">
       <option value="Ja" selected="">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="IDS" value="50">
      <input type="hidden" name="B" value="1">
      <p style="display:none;">1</p>
     </td></tr>
  
   <tr class="cus1">
   <td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="alles">
       <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee" selected="">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="40">
      <input type="hidden" name="A" value="0">
      <p style="display:none;">0</p>
     </td>
    
    <td style="width: 18%;">
     19-01-2017  10:28  
    </td>
    <td style="width: 16%;" class="left">
     Testpersoon 
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;" class="left">
     test
    </td>
    <td style="width: 22%;" class="left">
     jbsfdfn@ti.nl
    </td>
    <td style="width: 14%;" class="left">
     
    </td>
    <form method="post"></form><td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="geblokkeerd">
       <option value="Ja" selected="">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="IDS" value="40">
      <input type="hidden" name="B" value="1">
      <p style="display:none;">1</p>
     </td></tr>
  
   <tr class="cus1">
   <td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="alles">
       <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee" selected="">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="49">
      <input type="hidden" name="A" value="0">
      <p style="display:none;">0</p>
     </td>
    
    <td style="width: 18%;">
     19-01-2017  10:28  
    </td>
    <td style="width: 16%;" class="left">
     Testpersoon 
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;" class="left">
     test
    </td>
    <td style="width: 22%;" class="left">
     fdn@tiftrrd.nl
    </td>
    <td style="width: 14%;" class="left">
     
    </td>
    <form method="post"></form><td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="geblokkeerd">
       <option value="Ja" selected="">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="IDS" value="49">
      <input type="hidden" name="B" value="1">
      <p style="display:none;">1</p>
     </td></tr>
  
   <tr class="cus1">
   <td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="alles">
       <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee" selected="">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="34">
      <input type="hidden" name="A" value="0">
      <p style="display:none;">0</p>
     </td>
    
    <td style="width: 18%;">
     19-01-2017  10:28  
    </td>
    <td style="width: 16%;" class="left">
     Kees de jong 
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;" class="left">
     trined
    </td>
    <td style="width: 22%;" class="left">
     jboan@trined.nl
    </td>
    <td style="width: 14%;" class="left">
     0643937984
    </td>
    <form method="post"></form><td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="geblokkeerd">
       <option value="Ja" selected="">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="IDS" value="34">
      <input type="hidden" name="B" value="1">
      <p style="display:none;">1</p>
     </td></tr>
  
   <tr class="cus1">
   <td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="alles">
       <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee" selected="">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="47">
      <input type="hidden" name="A" value="0">
      <p style="display:none;">0</p>
     </td>
    
    <td style="width: 18%;">
     19-01-2017  10:28  
    </td>
    <td style="width: 16%;" class="left">
     Testpersoon 
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;" class="left">
     test
    </td>
    <td style="width: 22%;" class="left">
     fdn@tifddddsd.nl
    </td>
    <td style="width: 14%;" class="left">
     
    </td>
    <form method="post"></form><td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="geblokkeerd">
       <option value="Ja" selected="">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="IDS" value="47">
      <input type="hidden" name="B" value="1">
      <p style="display:none;">1</p>
     </td></tr>
  
   <tr class="cus1">
   <td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="alles">
       <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee" selected="">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="51">
      <input type="hidden" name="A" value="0">
      <p style="display:none;">0</p>
     </td>
    
    <td style="width: 18%;">
     19-01-2017  10:28  
    </td>
    <td style="width: 16%;" class="left">
     Testpersoon 
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;" class="left">
     test
    </td>
    <td style="width: 22%;" class="left">
     fdrtgg@tisdrd.nl
    </td>
    <td style="width: 14%;" class="left">
     
    </td>
    <form method="post"></form><td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="geblokkeerd">
       <option value="Ja" selected="">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="IDS" value="51">
      <input type="hidden" name="B" value="1">
      <p style="display:none;">1</p>
     </td></tr>
  
   <tr class="cus1">
   <td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="alles">
       <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee" selected="">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="35">
      <input type="hidden" name="A" value="0">
      <p style="display:none;">0</p>
     </td>
    
    <td style="width: 18%;">
     19-01-2017  10:28  
    </td>
    <td style="width: 16%;" class="left">
     Testpersoon 
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;" class="left">
     test
    </td>
    <td style="width: 22%;" class="left">
     jboan@trinedd.nl
    </td>
    <td style="width: 14%;" class="left">
     
    </td>
    <form method="post"></form><td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="geblokkeerd">
       <option value="Ja" selected="">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="IDS" value="35">
      <input type="hidden" name="B" value="1">
      <p style="display:none;">1</p>
     </td></tr>
  
   <tr class="cus1">
   <td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="alles">
       <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee" selected="">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="41">
      <input type="hidden" name="A" value="0">
      <p style="display:none;">0</p>
     </td>
    
    <td style="width: 18%;">
     19-01-2017  10:28  
    </td>
    <td style="width: 16%;" class="left">
     Testpersoon 
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;" class="left">
     test
    </td>
    <td style="width: 22%;" class="left">
     jbsfdfn@tidsd.nl
    </td>
    <td style="width: 14%;" class="left">
     
    </td>
    <form method="post"></form><td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="geblokkeerd">
       <option value="Ja" selected="">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="IDS" value="41">
      <input type="hidden" name="B" value="1">
      <p style="display:none;">1</p>
     </td></tr>
  
   <tr class="cus1">
   <td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="alles">
       <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee" selected="">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="44">
      <input type="hidden" name="A" value="0">
      <p style="display:none;">0</p>
     </td>
    
    <td style="width: 18%;">
     19-01-2017  10:28  
    </td>
    <td style="width: 16%;" class="left">
     Testpersoon 
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;" class="left">
     test
    </td>
    <td style="width: 22%;" class="left">
     fdsdfn@tifdddsd.nl
    </td>
    <td style="width: 14%;" class="left">
     
    </td>
    <form method="post"></form><td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="geblokkeerd">
       <option value="Ja" selected="">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="IDS" value="44">
      <input type="hidden" name="B" value="1">
      <p style="display:none;">1</p>
     </td></tr>
  
   <tr class="cus1">
   <td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="alles">
       <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee" selected="">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="52">
      <input type="hidden" name="A" value="0">
      <p style="display:none;">0</p>
     </td>
    
    <td style="width: 18%;">
     19-01-2017  10:28  
    </td>
    <td style="width: 16%;" class="left">
     Testpersoon 
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;" class="left">
     test
    </td>
    <td style="width: 22%;" class="left">
     fdrtgg@tisfredrd.nl
    </td>
    <td style="width: 14%;" class="left">
     
    </td>
    <form method="post"></form><td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="geblokkeerd">
       <option value="Ja" selected="">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="IDS" value="52">
      <input type="hidden" name="B" value="1">
      <p style="display:none;">1</p>
     </td></tr>
  
   <tr class="cus1">
   <td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="alles">
       <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee" selected="">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="46">
      <input type="hidden" name="A" value="0">
      <p style="display:none;">0</p>
     </td>
    
    <td style="width: 18%;">
     19-01-2017  10:28  
    </td>
    <td style="width: 16%;" class="left">
     Testpersoon 
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;" class="left">
     test
    </td>
    <td style="width: 22%;" class="left">
     fdsdfn@tifddddsd.nl
    </td>
    <td style="width: 14%;" class="left">
     
    </td>
    <form method="post"></form><td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="geblokkeerd">
       <option value="Ja" selected="">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="IDS" value="46">
      <input type="hidden" name="B" value="1">
      <p style="display:none;">1</p>
     </td></tr>
  
   <tr class="cus1">
   <td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="alles">
       <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee" selected="">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="33">
      <input type="hidden" name="A" value="0">
      <p style="display:none;">0</p>
     </td>
    
    <td style="width: 18%;">
     19-01-2017  10:28  
    </td>
    <td style="width: 16%;" class="left">
     Kees de jong 
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;" class="left">
     trined
    </td>
    <td style="width: 22%;" class="left">
     jboan@team.trined.n
    </td>
    <td style="width: 14%;" class="left">
     0642937984
    </td>
    <form method="post"></form><td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="geblokkeerd">
       <option value="Ja" selected="">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="IDS" value="33">
      <input type="hidden" name="B" value="1">
      <p style="display:none;">1</p>
     </td></tr>
  
   <tr class="cus1">
   <td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="alles">
       <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee" selected="">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="45">
      <input type="hidden" name="A" value="0">
      <p style="display:none;">0</p>
     </td>
    
    <td style="width: 18%;">
     19-01-2017  10:28  
    </td>
    <td style="width: 16%;" class="left">
     Testpersoon 
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;" class="left">
     test
    </td>
    <td style="width: 22%;" class="left">
     fdsdccdfn@tifdddsd.nl
    </td>
    <td style="width: 14%;" class="left">
     
    </td>
    <form method="post"></form><td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="geblokkeerd">
       <option value="Ja" selected="">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="IDS" value="45">
      <input type="hidden" name="B" value="1">
      <p style="display:none;">1</p>
     </td></tr>
  
   <tr class="cus1">
   <td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="alles">
       <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee" selected="">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="42">
      <input type="hidden" name="A" value="0">
      <p style="display:none;">0</p>
     </td>
    
    <td style="width: 18%;">
     19-01-2017  10:28  
    </td>
    <td style="width: 16%;" class="left">
     Testpersoon 
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;" class="left">
     test
    </td>
    <td style="width: 22%;" class="left">
     jbsfgfgdfdfn@tidsd.nl
    </td>
    <td style="width: 14%;" class="left">
     
    </td>
    <form method="post"></form><td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="geblokkeerd">
       <option value="Ja" selected="">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="IDS" value="42">
      <input type="hidden" name="B" value="1">
      <p style="display:none;">1</p>
     </td></tr>
  
   <tr class="cus1">
   <td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="alles">
       <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee" selected="">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="32">
      <input type="hidden" name="A" value="0">
      <p style="display:none;">0</p>
     </td>
    
    <td style="width: 18%;">
     19-01-2017  10:28  
    </td>
    <td style="width: 16%;" class="left">
     Kees de jong 
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;" class="left">
     trined
    </td>
    <td style="width: 22%;" class="left">
     jbotman@team.trined.nl
    </td>
    <td style="width: 14%;" class="left">
     0642937988
    </td>
    <form method="post"></form><td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="geblokkeerd">
       <option value="Ja" selected="">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="IDS" value="32">
      <input type="hidden" name="B" value="1">
      <p style="display:none;">1</p>
     </td></tr>
  
   <tr class="cus1">
   <td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="alles">
       <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee" selected="">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="43">
      <input type="hidden" name="A" value="0">
      <p style="display:none;">0</p>
     </td>
    
    <td style="width: 18%;">
     19-01-2017  10:28  
    </td>
    <td style="width: 16%;" class="left">
     Testpersoon 
    </td>
    <td style="width: 10%;" class="left">
     test
    </td>
    <td style="width: 22%;" class="left">
     jbsfgfgdfdfn@tifddsd.nl
    </td>
    <td style="width: 14%;" class="left">
     
    </td>
    <form method="post"></form><td style="width: 10%;">
      <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="geblokkeerd">
       <option value="Ja">Ja</option>
       <option value="Nee" selected="">Nee</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="IDS" value="43">
      <input type="hidden" name="B" value="0">
      <p style="display:none;">0</p>
     </td>
     </tr>   
  </tbody></table>
```

How can I make my tbody scrollable?
Can someone please edit my snippet and make it scrollable?
I can sort already and now I need to scroll inside the table BODY!!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody

Comment: that didn't work for me, already tried

Comment: @JelleBotman i've try the solution it works good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your tbody absolue.
https://jsfiddle.net/qmmg0pu4/

```
tbody{
   position:absolute;
   max-height:200px;
   overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Comment: no its not better, it must be a normal table with the tableheader at the same width as the tablebody