# How to scroll tbody?

Tags: css

I want a table to have a scrollable tbody, but headers should not scroll.

The table should not occupy 100% width. The columns should not be wider than the content.

How do I do that?

Trying at https://jsfiddle.net/vxmyh826/4/ to make it look like

[image: table with desired scrolling]

With the css

```
table
{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  max-height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

tbody
{
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

and it will rather look something like

[image: result]

with the table border marked with red.

## edit

This is not a duplicate of the said link because I do not look for a solution that uses scripting (it is a css question).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML table with 100% width, with vertical scroll inside tbody](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody)

Comment: add `overflow: hidden;` on tbody so you can make use of scroll.

Comment: @DincaAdrian How `overflow: hidden;` can make content scrollable?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I just say the text overflowing and thought of hidden. The solution is a little more complex though. A complete solution is presented here with demos and pictures. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody

Comment: @malviya The accepted solution on that page suggests a script solution to set column widths which makes it not a duplicate.

Comment: @DincaAdrian The link was already suggested, but as I said, the accepted answer uses scripting.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Don Joe</td>
                <td>Itajai</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temp. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat no</td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
             ...
            </tr>
```

CSS

```
table{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

table th, table td{
    text-align: left;
    width: 25%;
}

table td{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

table tbody{
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 200px;
}

 table thead{
     width:100%;
     display: table;
 }
```

The "table tbody{ display:block; overflow: auto; height:200;}" make the tbody scroll but the width get mess. To correct you have to set "table thead{ width: calc(100% - 20px);display: table;}" and set the width for each column.

Answer (score 0):

```
table {
    display: inline-block;
}

tbody {
    display: block;
    height: 40rem;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To do the same you have to use two < thead > I.e.

```
< thead >
             Your th here
< / thead >
```

Repeat the thead again.

```
< thead  >
             Your th here
< / thead >
```

And then your `< tbody >`

It will resolve the issue.

Comment: I think you need to explain how this helps for it to be useful.