# percentage width on td/th not working (jsfiddle)

Tags: html, css

I would like to style a table **by pure css** whose header could be fixed while body can be scrollable vertically. 
 This is my [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vx1bvmxm/)

```css
/*css for fixed header, vertically scrollable body*/

.fixedHeader {
  width: 100%;
}

.fixedHeader thead {
  display: block;
  width: cal(100% - 17px);
}

.fixedHeader tbody {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


/*custom appearance for your table*/

.fixedHeader {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.fixedHeader th,
.fixedHeader td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<table class="fixedHeader">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>These are red.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pear</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>These are green.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Grape</td>
      <td>Purple / Green</td>
      <td>These are purple and green.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>These are orange.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td>Yellow</td>
      <td>These are yellow.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kiwi</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>These are green.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Plum</td>
      <td>Purple</td>
      <td>These are Purple</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Watermelon</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>These are red.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tomato</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>These are red.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cherry</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>These are red.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cantelope</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>These are orange inside.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Honeydew</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>These are green inside.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Papaya</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>These are green.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Raspberry</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>These are red.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blueberry</td>
      <td>Blue</td>
      <td>These are blue.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mango</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>These are orange.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Passion Fruit</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>These are green.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What confused me is that which is the element (perhaps my understandings are totally wrong, please correct me) that the percentage width on td/th refers to on earth?

Comment: Typo in your  `width:cal(100% - 17px);`. It must be `calc` not "cal".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML table with 100% width, with vertical scroll inside tbody](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody)

Comment: @shubhamagrawal Thanks for your providing. The key here is to adjust the width of th(s) to equal to the width of the corresponding column. But I still don't get that why relative width (percentage) on th/td not working?

Answer (score 0):

This link:
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/CrSpu/554/)
should work. Try using the CSS on this table to help. Here is the css:

```
table.scroll {
width: 100%; /* Optional */
/* border-collapse: collapse; */
border-spacing: 0;
border: 2px solid black;
}

table.scroll tbody,
table.scroll thead { display: block; }

thead tr th { 
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
/*text-align: left;*/
}

table.scroll tbody {
height: 100px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
}

tbody { border-top: 2px solid black; }

tbody td, thead th {
width: 20%; /* Optional */
border-right: 1px solid black;
}

tbody td:last-child, thead th:last-child {
border-right: none;
}
```

**EDIT**

The Javascript is the main key to this:

```
// Adjust the width of thead cells when window resizes
$(window).resize(function() {
// Get the tbody columns width array
colWidth = $bodyCells.map(function() {
    return $(this).width();
}).get();

// Set the width of thead columns
$table.find('thead tr').children().each(function(i, v) {
    $(v).width(colWidth[i]);
});    
}).resize(); // Trigger resize handler
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fixed width `td` and `th` and also give `position:fixed` to  `thead`. So `thead` will stay at top of table and `tbody` will scroll.

```css
.fixedHeader{
  width:480px;
   max-height:200px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  display:block;
}
.fixedHeader thead{
  position:fixed;
  background:blue;
  color:white
}
/*custom appearance for your table*/
.fixedHeader{
  border:1px solid gray;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

.fixedHeader th, .fixedHeader td{
  border:1px solid gray;
  width:150px
}
```

```html
<table class="fixedHeader">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>These are red.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pear</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>These are green.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Grape</td>
      <td>Purple / Green</td>
      <td>These are purple and green.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>These are orange.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td>Yellow</td>
      <td>These are yellow.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kiwi</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>These are green.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Plum</td>
      <td>Purple</td>
      <td>These are Purple</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Watermelon</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>These are red.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tomato</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>These are red.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cherry</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>These are red.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cantelope</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>These are orange inside.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Honeydew</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>These are green inside.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Papaya</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>These are green.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Raspberry</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>These are red.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blueberry</td>
      <td>Blue</td>
      <td>These are blue.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mango</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>These are orange.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Passion Fruit</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>These are green.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```