# how to make the HTML table scroll

Tags: java, html, css

i am trying to make my table scroll verticaly but it does not work. Can someone please help me?
here is my html code:

```
<div class = scroll>
            <table border="1">
             <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Number</th>
                    <th>Name</th>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    5
                      </td>
                    <td>
                    Hello
                     </td>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
```

here is my .css code:

```
.scroll{
    overflow:scroll;

}
```

Comment: Think you should check this 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML table with 100% width, with vertical scroll inside tbody](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody)

Comment: you are making a typo in your class attribute. It should be `class="whatever"`

Answer (score 1):

set `height` property in your css file

```css
#table-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#table-scroll {
  height: 120px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#table-wrapper table {
  width: 100%;
}

#table-wrapper table * {
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
}

#table-wrapper table thead th .text {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 20px;
  width: 35%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="table-wrapper">
  <div id="table-scroll">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><span class="text">A</span></th>
          <th><span class="text">B</span></th>
          <th><span class="text">C</span></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 0</td>
          <td>2, 0</td>
          <td>3, 0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 1</td>
          <td>2, 1</td>
          <td>3, 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 2</td>
          <td>2, 2</td>
          <td>3, 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 3</td>
          <td>2, 3</td>
          <td>3, 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 4</td>
          <td>2, 4</td>
          <td>3, 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 5</td>
          <td>2, 5</td>
          <td>3, 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 6</td>
          <td>2, 6</td>
          <td>3, 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 7</td>
          <td>2, 7</td>
          <td>3, 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 8</td>
          <td>2, 8</td>
          <td>3, 8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 9</td>
          <td>2, 9</td>
          <td>3, 9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 10</td>
          <td>2, 10</td>
          <td>3, 10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 11</td>
          <td>2, 11</td>
          <td>3, 11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 12</td>
          <td>2, 12</td>
          <td>3, 12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 13</td>
          <td>2, 13</td>
          <td>3, 13</td>
        </tr>
          <td>1, 17</td>
          <td>2, 17</td>
          <td>3, 17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 18</td>
          <td>2, 18</td>
          <td>3, 18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 19</td>
          <td>2, 19</td>
          <td>3, 19</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 20</td>
          <td>2, 20</td>
          <td>3, 20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 24</td>
          <td>2, 24</td>
          <td>3, 24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 25</td>
          <td>2, 25</td>
          <td>3, 25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 26</td>
          <td>2, 26</td>
          <td>3, 26</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 27</td>
          <td>2, 27</td>
          <td>3, 27</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 28</td>
          <td>2, 28</td>
          <td>3, 28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 29</td>
          <td>2, 29</td>
          <td>3, 29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 30</td>
          <td>2, 30</td>
          <td>3, 30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 31</td>
          <td>2, 31</td>
          <td>3, 31</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 32</td>
          <td>2, 32</td>
          <td>3, 32</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 33</td>
          <td>2, 33</td>
          <td>3, 33</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 34</td>
          <td>2, 34</td>
          <td>3, 34</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 35</td>
          <td>2, 35</td>
          <td>3, 35</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 36</td>
          <td>2, 36</td>
          <td>3, 36</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 37</td>
          <td>2, 37</td>
          <td>3, 37</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 38</td>
          <td>2, 38</td>
          <td>3, 38</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 39</td>
          <td>2, 39</td>
          <td>3, 39</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 40</td>
          <td>2, 40</td>
          <td>3, 40</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 41</td>
          <td>2, 41</td>
          <td>3, 41</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 42</td>
          <td>2, 42</td>
          <td>3, 42</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 43</td>
          <td>2, 43</td>
          <td>3, 43</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 44</td>
          <td>2, 44</td>
          <td>3, 44</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 45</td>
          <td>2, 45</td>
          <td>3, 45</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 46</td>
          <td>2, 46</td>
          <td>3, 46</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 47</td>
          <td>2, 47</td>
          <td>3, 47</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 48</td>
          <td>2, 48</td>
          <td>3, 48</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 49</td>
          <td>2, 49</td>
          <td>3, 49</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 50</td>
          <td>2, 50</td>
          <td>3, 50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 51</td>
          <td>2, 51</td>
          <td>3, 51</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 52</td>
          <td>2, 52</td>
          <td>3, 52</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 53</td>
          <td>2, 53</td>
          <td>3, 53</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 54</td>
          <td>2, 54</td>
          <td>3, 54</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 55</td>
          <td>2, 55</td>
          <td>3, 55</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 56</td>
          <td>2, 56</td>
          <td>3, 56</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 57</td>
          <td>2, 57</td>
          <td>3, 57</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 58</td>
          <td>2, 58</td>
          <td>3, 58</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 59</td>
          <td>2, 59</td>
          <td>3, 59</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 60</td>
          <td>2, 60</td>
          <td>3, 60</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 61</td>
          <td>2, 61</td>
          <td>3, 61</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 62</td>
          <td>2, 62</td>
          <td>3, 62</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 63</td>
          <td>2, 63</td>
          <td>3, 63</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 64</td>
          <td>2, 64</td>
          <td>3, 64</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 65</td>
          <td>2, 65</td>
          <td>3, 65</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 66</td>
          <td>2, 66</td>
          <td>3, 66</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 67</td>
          <td>2, 67</td>
          <td>3, 67</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 68</td>
          <td>2, 68</td>
          <td>3, 68</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 69</td>
          <td>2, 69</td>
          <td>3, 69</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 70</td>
          <td>2, 70</td>
          <td>3, 70</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 71</td>
          <td>2, 71</td>
          <td>3, 71</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 72</td>
          <td>2, 72</td>
          <td>3, 72</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 73</td>
          <td>2, 73</td>
          <td>3, 73</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 74</td>
          <td>2, 74</td>
          <td>3, 74</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 75</td>
          <td>2, 75</td>
          <td>3, 75</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 76</td>
          <td>2, 76</td>
          <td>3, 76</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 77</td>
          <td>2, 77</td>
          <td>3, 77</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 78</td>
          <td>2, 78</td>
          <td>3, 78</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 79</td>
          <td>2, 79</td>
          <td>3, 79</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 80</td>
          <td>2, 80</td>
          <td>3, 80</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 81</td>
          <td>2, 81</td>
          <td>3, 81</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 82</td>
          <td>2, 82</td>
          <td>3, 82</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 83</td>
          <td>2, 83</td>
          <td>3, 83</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 84</td>
          <td>2, 84</td>
          <td>3, 84</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 85</td>
          <td>2, 85</td>
          <td>3, 85</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 86</td>
          <td>2, 86</td>
          <td>3, 86</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 87</td>
          <td>2, 87</td>
          <td>3, 87</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 88</td>
          <td>2, 88</td>
          <td>3, 88</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 89</td>
          <td>2, 89</td>
          <td>3, 89</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 90</td>
          <td>2, 90</td>
          <td>3, 90</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 91</td>
          <td>2, 91</td>
          <td>3, 91</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 92</td>
          <td>2, 92</td>
          <td>3, 92</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 93</td>
          <td>2, 93</td>
          <td>3, 93</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 94</td>
          <td>2, 94</td>
          <td>3, 94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 95</td>
          <td>2, 95</td>
          <td>3, 95</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 96</td>
          <td>2, 96</td>
          <td>3, 96</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 97</td>
          <td>2, 97</td>
          <td>3, 97</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 98</td>
          <td>2, 98</td>
          <td>3, 98</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1, 99</td>
          <td>2, 99</td>
          <td>3, 99</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the table to scroll vertically you have to set a height for the container with the class "scroll". See sample below

```css
.scroll{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    max-height: 100px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class = scroll>
  <table border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Hello</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Hello</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Hello</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Hello</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Hello</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```