# trying to expand <tr> width and make it match <td> width without breaking jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been using this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mathijsflietstra/X2Kmd/1/) but the only problem is some of my td cells are much bigger than this example and I can't get the header cells to align with the body cells without causing the scroll bars to disappear. This is what happens when a cell is [too big.](http://jsfiddle.net/X2Kmd/1297/)

```
<style type="text/css">
.fieldset-auto-width 
{
    display: inline-block;
}
html 
{
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 10pt;
    line-height: 25px;
}
table 
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 1000px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display: block;
}
thead 
{
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
thead, tbody 
{
    display: block;
}
tbody 
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 140px;
}
td, th 
{
    min-width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
table.big td th
{
    width: 200px;
}
</style>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
            <th>Column 4</th>
            <th>Column 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Rowaaahhhhhaaaa 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

$('table').on('scroll', function () {
    $("table > *").width($("table").width() + $("table").scrollLeft());
});
```

I noticed when I take out "display: block;" it causes the headers and body cells to match, but that breaks the scroll bars. I tried this display: grouping element but that also breaks the scrolls. I tried setting the width in the particularly large cells but it had no effect, I tried making a class and putting the class in the  and  cells but it also had no effect, it almost feels impossible to fix. Can someone please help me?

Comment: I think the 'colspan' property will help.

Comment: i put that in the <th> and <tr> and that did nothing

Comment: try read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody