# html table make 2nd tbody scrollable

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

i have this `fiddle` - https://jsfiddle.net/nish4114/u4kfxc48/

and wanted to make a scroll only on the second tbody so that after 4 or 5 td there should be a scroll in it and also header should be fixed

Please let me know how to make it possible

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody

Comment: batter way is you create second table inside table instead of second tbody.

Answer (score 0):

Add below Class to second table tbody:

```
.table2Scroll {
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

**Now Try this :**

```
thead, tbody {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
}
tbody:nth-child(4) {
  height: 75px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 400px;
}

th, td {
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: there got some alignment error in the second table isnt it ?