# HTML table with 100% width, with vertical scroll inside tbody without td wdth

Tags: jquery, html, css, vertical-scrolling

I have tried the solution posted by Hashem Qolami  in post [HTML table with 100% width, with vertical scroll inside tbody](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17067294/5840390), but am having issues.

[image: Tried Scenario-Issue]

Let me fill you in, in case you require additional details.

I've tried multiple posts. Everywhere I have found only fixed width for `td` in `tbody`. But I require a dynamic width, according to the data in `tbody`.

It is working in sites when there are different sections of js, css.
But not working when i combine everything to a single html.
My Html image:[HTML Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqM15.png)

```js
// Change the selector if needed
var $table = $('table.scroll'),
  $bodyCells = $table.find('tbody tr:first').children(),
  colWidth;

// Adjust the width of thead cells when window resizes
$(window).resize(function() {
  // Get the tbody columns width array
  colWidth = $bodyCells.map(function() {
    return $(this).width();
    alert("hii");
  }).get();

  // Set the width of thead columns
  $table.find('thead tr').children().each(function(i, v) {
    $(v).width(colWidth[i]);
  });
}).resize(); // Trigger resize handler
```

```css
table.scroll {
  /* width: 100%; */
  /* Optional */
  /* border-collapse: collapse; */
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

table.scroll tbody,
table.scroll thead {
  display: block;
}

thead tr th {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  /* text-align: left; */
}

table.scroll tbody {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

tbody {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
}

tbody td,
thead th {
  /* width: 20%; */
  /* Optional */
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  /* white-space: nowrap; */
}

tbody td:last-child,
thead th:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="scroll">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Head 1</th>
      <th>Head 2</th>
      <th>Head 3</th>
      <th>Head 4</th>
      <th>Head 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Uncomment your table width

```
table.scroll {
  width: 100%;
  /* Optional */
  /* border-collapse: collapse; */
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 2px solid black;
 }
```

Please try [this](http://jsbin.com/difoteg/edit?html,css,js,output)

Cells are responding accordingly when resized.

Comment: Thanks for your help.but i m nt sure what am i dng wrong when i m trying to run entire html it does nt work..it works when i m trying to use these other sources of code templates. Can you please suggest..I have added a screenshot of my html as image in an edit..