# Table not resizing columns as per % in colgroup

Tags: html, css

Can someone advise on why the columns aren't resizing according to their %s in colgroup?

**PROBLEM: Make something like 50% first column 25% second column and third. While preserving display block on the tbody, such that we have scroll on the body not the whole table. SOLUTION: Leave in all the code like is below, but use td:nth-child property to manually set % width instead of using colgroup (because it required that display is not block but table-row-group).**

I have tried using '3*','1*','1*' for the col width as well, to no avail. I think it must have to do something with the fact that I am placing the table inside a div container or due to display:block property, perhaps it has to be display: table. But when I do display: table, then table takes up only 50% of the container space and floats to left and columns are still of equal width. Thanks for any help!

EDIT: I have also tried `style="width: 100%"` on the table.

**EDIT EDIT: removing `display:block` from `.fixed_header thead tr` and `.fixed_header tbody` fixes the issue for the header. Also, setting `width:100%` in `.fixed_header th, .fixed_header td` almost fixes it, it is a little bit misalligned.**

```css
.table-container {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 94%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 15px;
}

// https://codepen.io/GhostRider/pen/GHaFw
.style-2::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.style-2::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 width: 12px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.style-2::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
 border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 background-color: #F4F7F7;
}

table, tbody {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.fixed_header{
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.fixed_header tbody{
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 90%;
}

.fixed_header thead tr {
   display: block;
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.fixed_header th, .fixed_header td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">

                            <table class="fixed_header">
                              <colgroup style="width: 100%;">
                                  <col span="1" style="width: 50%;">
                                  <col span="1" style="width: 25%;">
                                  <col span="1" style="width: 25%;">
                              </colgroup>

                              <thead>
                                <tr>
                                  <th>Factor</th>
                                  <th>y_i</th>
                                  <th>F_i</th>
                                </tr>
                              </thead>

                              <tbody class="style-2">
                                <tr>
                                  <td>row 1-0</td>
                                  <td>row 1-1</td>
                                  <td>row 1-2</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>row 2-0</td>
                                  <td>row 2-1</td>
                                  <td>row 2-2</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>row 3-0</td>
                                  <td>row 3-1</td>
                                  <td>row 3-2</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>row 4-0</td>
                                  <td>row 4-1</td>
                                  <td>row 4-2</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>row 5-0</td>
                                  <td>row 5-1</td>
                                  <td>row 5-2</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>row 6-0</td>
                                  <td>row 6-1</td>
                                  <td>row 6-2</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>row 7-0</td>
                                  <td>row 7-1</td>
                                  <td>row 7-2</td>
                                </tr>
                              <tr>
                                  <td>row 7-0</td>
                                  <td>row 7-1</td>
                                  <td>row 7-2</td>
                                </tr>
                              <tr>
                                  <td>row 7-0</td>
                                  <td>row 7-1</td>
                                  <td>row 7-2</td>
                                </tr>
                              <tr>
                                  <td>row 7-0</td>
                                  <td>row 7-1</td>
                                  <td>row 7-2</td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                            </div>
```

Comment: html 5 is now support col-width.https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_colgroup.asp

Comment: see Attributes-Description

Comment: so what is the alternative?

Comment: no, colgroup is working in HTML5

Answer (score 2):

Removing the below classes solved the issue.

```
table, tbody {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    table-layout: fixed;
}


.fixed_header tbody{
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 90%;
}

.fixed_header thead tr {
   display: block;
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

I see the default display `table-row-group` of the tbody has been replaced with `display:inline-block` . My  guess is that these display properties  seen below make elements behave like tables and their children and consequently apply table grouping rules on them. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v6u197LL/) here

`display: table;
  display: table-cell;
  display: table-column;
  display: table-colgroup;
  display: table-header-group;
  display: table-row-group;
  display: table-footer-group;
  display: table-row;
  display: table-caption;`

Comment: Great. I have also just noticed that, but removing inline-block, also removes overflow on the y axis

Comment: Cant we wrap the table in a div and achieve scrolling via the parent div? i.e if that is the ask :)

Comment: we have to achieve scrolling around tbody, not the whole thing (including thead), and it removes my div, when I put it around tbody :O

Comment: oh no, they want me to change it back to display: block. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody

Comment: ah ! the old fixed header problem :O ... as i understand you wanna have the header fixed for  a table with variable column widths !..

Comment: I want, in this particular case, something like: 50% first column, 25% second and 25% third, and at the same time have scrollbar on tbody, not the whole thing. I have noticed, that that Fiddle, is not quite what I need, it is almost what  I need, apart from the fixed % width columns.

Comment: hmmm, maybe I should you use n-th child css selector and set every first td in each tr to 50% and every other td to 25%. That might work! Then we can keep display: block for tbody, and omit using colgroup.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table style="width: 100%">
<colgroup>
   <col span="1" style="width: 50%;">
   <col span="1" style="width: 25%;">
   <col span="1" style="width: 25%;">
</colgroup>



<!-- Put <thead>, <tbody>, and <tr>'s here! -->
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color: #777">50%</td>
        <td style="background-color: #aaa">25%</td>
        <td style="background-color: #777">25%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 1-0</td>
      <td>row 1-1</td>
      <td>row 1-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 2-0</td>
      <td>row 2-1</td>
      <td>row 2-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 3-0</td>
      <td>row 3-1</td>
      <td>row 3-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 4-0</td>
      <td>row 4-1</td>
      <td>row 4-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 5-0</td>
      <td>row 5-1</td>
      <td>row 5-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 6-0</td>
      <td>row 6-1</td>
      <td>row 6-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 7-0</td>
      <td>row 7-1</td>
      <td>row 7-2</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>row 7-0</td>
      <td>row 7-1</td>
      <td>row 7-2</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>row 7-0</td>
      <td>row 7-1</td>
      <td>row 7-2</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>row 7-0</td>
      <td>row 7-1</td>
      <td>row 7-2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Try this! I hope this help. Is working for me.

Comment: Why is it answering the op question ?

Comment: I have seen this. It is not answering my q

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="table-container">

                            <table class="fixed_header" style="width: 100%;">


                              <thead>
                                <tr>
                                  <th style="width: 50%;">Factor</th>
                                  <th style="width: 25%;">y_i</th>
                                  <th style="width: 25%;">F_i Factor </th>
                                </tr>
                              </thead>

                              <tbody class="style-2">
                                <tr>
                                  <td>row 1-0</td>
                                  <td>row 1-1</td>
                                  <td>row 1-2</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>row 2-0</td>
                                  <td>row 2-1</td>
                                  <td>row 2-2</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>row 3-0</td>
                                  <td>row 3-1</td>
                                  <td>row 3-2</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>row 4-0</td>
                                  <td>row 4-1</td>
                                  <td>row 4-2</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>row 5-0</td>
                                  <td>row 5-1</td>
                                  <td>row 5-2</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>row 6-0</td>
                                  <td>row 6-1</td>
                                  <td>row 6-2</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>row 7-0</td>
                                  <td>row 7-1</td>
                                  <td>row 7-2</td>
                                </tr>
                              <tr>
                                  <td>row 7-0</td>
                                  <td>row 7-1</td>
                                  <td>row 7-2</td>
                                </tr>
                              <tr>
                                  <td>row 7-0</td>
                                  <td>row 7-1</td>
                                  <td>row 7-2</td>
                                </tr>
                              <tr>
                                  <td>row 7-0</td>
                                  <td>row 7-1</td>
                                  <td>row 7-2</td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                            </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain why this is answering the OP question

Answer (score 0):

**Please add this CSS :**
Is working for me

*{ text-align: left; }
table{ width: 100%; max-width: 600px; }