# Set html table column's width based on header width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get my html table working with vertical scrollbar for `tbody` based on [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody). I got the scrollbar working but struggling to dynamically set the width of the columns. The suggested SO answer setting the width of the header columns based on the width of tbody columns. I want to do exactly opposite. I am trying to set width of tbody columns ( first row only) based on header column width.

[JSfiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dnbu9whp/11/)

**html**

```
<table class="table mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="border-top:2px solid #ddd"></th>
            <th colspan="4" style="text-align:center;border-left:1px solid #ddd;border-right:1px solid #ddd;border-top:2px solid #ddd">Group 1</th>
            <th colspan="4" style="text-align:center;border-left:1px solid #ddd;border-right:1px solid #ddd;border-top:2px solid #ddd">Group 2</th>
            <th style="border-top:2px solid #ddd">Group 3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:200px">Col 1</th>
            <th style="width:150px;border-left:1px solid #ddd">Col 2</th>
            <th style="width:150px">Col 3</th>
            <th style="width:150px" class="td-md">Col 4</th>
            <th style="width:150px">Col 5</th>            
            <th style="width:150px;border-left:1px solid #ddd">Col 6</th>
            <th style="width:150px">Col 7</th>
            <th style="width:150px">Col 8</th>
            <th style="width:150px">Col 9</th>
            <th style="width:150px;border-left:1px solid #ddd">Col 10</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A12345</td>
            <td>1254</td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>43243</td>
            <td>432</td>
            <td>4323</td>
            <td>4324</td>
            <td>434</td>
            <td>4343244</td>
            <td>4343244</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A12345</td>
            <td>1254</td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>43243</td>
            <td>432</td>
            <td>4323</td>
            <td>4324</td>
            <td>434</td>
            <td>4343244</td>
            <td>4343244</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A12345</td>
            <td>1254</td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>43243</td>
            <td>432</td>
            <td>4323</td>
            <td>4324</td>
            <td>434</td>
            <td>4343244</td>
            <td>4343244</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A12345</td>
            <td>1254</td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>43243</td>
            <td>432</td>
            <td>4323</td>
            <td>4324</td>
            <td>434</td>
            <td>4343244</td>
            <td>4343244</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A12345</td>
            <td>1254</td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>43243</td>
            <td>432</td>
            <td>4323</td>
            <td>4324</td>
            <td>434</td>
            <td>4343244</td>
            <td>4343244</td>
        </tr>        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {

       // Change the selector if needed
    var $table = $('.mytable'),
        $bodyCells = $table.find('thead tr:nth-child(2) th'),
        colWidth;
    var alertWidth = '';


    // Get the header columns width array
    colWidth = $bodyCells.map(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
        alertWidth += $this.width() + ","; 
        return $this.width();
    }).get();

        alert(alertWidth);

    // Set the width of first row's column
    $table.find('tbody tr:first td').each(function(i, v) {
        //alert(colWidth[i]);
        $(v).width(colWidth[i]);
    });

})
```

**css**

```
 thead, tbody {
        display: block;
    }

    tbody {
        height: 100px; /* Just for the demo          */
        overflow-y: auto; /* Trigger vertical scroll    */
        overflow-x: hidden; /* Hide the horizontal scroll */
    }
```

**ISSUE**
Issue here is jquery's `width()` function does not return the same value as what is set on `th`. If i inspect html in the browser the `width` property of `td` does not match with corresponding `th`
I have tried `.css("width")` as well with noluck. I

Comment: thead doesn't scroll but tbody does or might, you should mind this too.

Answer (score -2):

Remove the java-script and replace all css with this:

```
table ,tr td{
    border:1px solid red
}
tbody {
    display:block;
    height:200px;
    overflow:auto;
}
thead, tbody tr {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;/* even columns width , fix width of table too*/
}
thead {
    width: calc( 100% - 1em )/* scrollbar is average 1em/16px width, remove it from thead width */
}
table {
    width:400px;
}
```

Comment: with your suggestion i dont get vertical scrollbar https://jsfiddle.net/f8r5na3j/

Comment: Updated my answer and added the code to create the vertical scrollbar

Comment: that will add the scrollbar to entire table not just for tbody. you may want to check SO link i have in OP