# How to avoid Flickering div due to show and hide scrollbar on mouse enter

Tags: html, css

I am showing a scroll bar on mouse hover and it makes a flicker effect in UI. Can anyone suggest how to avoid it? The code is here

```css
  .parent {
        width:100%;
        max-height: 400px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
      }
     .parent:hover {
        overflow-y: scroll;
     }
     .table {
       width: 100%;
     }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <table class="table">
      <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: The exact code to reproduce the issue is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wjd2f6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Is it a common problem and can't be fixed?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here **within your question** and NEVER  a third party site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstyl you can add CSS `width:` to scroll bar. After that, add to `.parent{}` width (subtract scroll bar width from 100%).You can use CSS `calc();` function for this. When you hover parent, add CSS width 100% . 
But if you want to use the table width absolutely 100%, there is a guy solved via jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17380697/8660891
 *Sorry for my bad English :)

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;
    padding:0px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  min-height:50px;
  background-color:#888;
  height: 50px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #e3e3e3;
}
.parent {
        width:calc(100% - 15px);
        max-height: 200px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
      }
     
     .parent:hover {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        width: 100%;
     }
     .table {
       width: 100%;
     }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <table class="table">
      <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi This solution works for Chrome and not for firefox. Is there a way to work on FF

Comment: Can you try this `::-moz-scrollbar { width: 15px; }` on Firefox. I dont use now FF. I ifthis solve problem, i will add to my answer' css code. @balaG

Comment: This worked perfect but if we dont have that much of content for scroll then its flickering.

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

1. add a margin to the right at the same size of the scroll width (I believe default to be 16px). `margin-right: 16px`. I'm not pretty sure about this method though.
2. If you don't care too much about cross-browser compatibility, just use `overflow: overlay` and you got it

**Edit**: IE is dead so we can all be happy now with #2

Comment: 2nd option works a charm in the Electron app. thanks

Comment: `overflow: overlay` rocks!

Comment: @AntonioOoi it does indeed!

Answer (score 1):

If this table is to be scrollable, its bad UI practice to only show that it is scrollable when the user hovers over it (what about touch devices?).

The best way to solve this and the flickering would be to not hide the scrollbars at all  like so:

```
  .parent {
        width:100%;
        max-height: 400px;
        overflow-y: scroll; // or overflow-y:auto; 
      }
     .table {
       width: 100%;
     }
```

Comment: There is a CSS property to address this now, scrollbar-gutter:stable .  https://twitter.com/Ibelick/status/1720777069456453954

Answer (score 0):

Use this trick to solve that:

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.parent:hover,
.parent:focus {
  visibility: visible;
}

.child {
  visibility: visible;
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <td>Key</td>
        <td>Value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Key</td>
        <td>Value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Key</td>
        <td>Value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Key</td>
        <td>Value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Key</td>
        <td>Value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Key</td>
        <td>Value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Key</td>
        <td>Value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Key</td>
        <td>Value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Key</td>
        <td>Value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Key</td>
        <td>Value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Key</td>
        <td>Value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Key</td>
        <td>Value</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding a child div and using visibility. See the code.

Comment: Thank you for explaining yourself. You should do that every time. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thank you Rob. I'll do it. CSS isn't like other programming languages that implement algorithms.In CSS world some techniques have been found by developers and they are hard to explain.

Comment: When an element `visibility: hidden;` hides the element, but it still takes up space in the layout. Descendants of the element will be visible if they have visibility set to visible. Now we know why child is visible. Easily you can change the visibility  parent on the hover event.

Answer (score 0):

instead of manually adding the scrollbar width you can use the [scrollbar-gutter](https://scrollbar-gutter) CSS property:

> The scrollbar-gutter CSS property allows authors to reserve space for the scrollbar, preventing unwanted layout changes as the content grows while also avoiding unnecessary visuals when scrolling isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

This resolved the issue for me:

```
scrollbar-gutter: stable both-edges;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scrollbars-custom and fixed the flicker issue by setting the margin right as 0px to the ScrollbarsCustom-Scroller and also setting the inset to 0px for the ScrollbarsCustom-Wrapper to maintain the padding of the container.