# thead and tbody doesnt fit

Tags: html, css, html-table

let me ask about the table on the CSS,

I've searched my best on google and related articles on StackOverflow but still can't find the way I want it to work,

I currently get an assignment with the following conditions:

1. scrollable tbody,
2. Thead is given a background color and a border for the tbody

I have done everything, but now there is a new constraint, the data in the tbody and thead columns cannot be aligned.

here's my snippet for html:

```css
table {
  font-size: medium;
}

.table-contract {
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px var(--uwongke-tertiary-color);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  empty-cells: show;
}

.table-contract thead th {
  background: var(--uwongke-tertiary-color);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px var(--uwongke-tertiary-color);
  color: var(--uwongke-light);
}

.table-contract thead th:first-child {
  background: var(--uwongke-tertiary-color);
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
}

.table-contract thead th:last-child {
  background: var(--uwongke-tertiary-color);
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}

.table-contract tr th,
.table-contract tr td {
  padding: 1.25rem;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.table-contract td.desc {
  width: 50%;
}

.table-contract,
.table-contract th,
.table-contract td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}


/* .table-contract thead, */

.table-contract tbody {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table-contract tbody {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 50rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.table-contract tr {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-borderless text-center mb-0 table-contract">
  <thead class="text-capitalize">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="">&nbsp;</th>
      <th scope="col" class="">No</th>
      <th scope="col" class="">pasal</th>
      <th scope="col" class="desc">deskripsi</th>
      <th scope="col" class="">modifikasi</th>
      <th scope="col" class="">aksi</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="text-capitalize" id="table_drag">

    <tr class="sorted-row">
      <td>=</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="judul-bab">pasal 1</td>
      <td class="desc">merupakan isi untuk pasal yang berkaitan dengan aturan aturan perusahaan untuk pegawai dan ketetapan lainnya</td>
      <td>27 jan, 09:57am</td>
      <td>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <button class="btn btn-edit" onclick="edit(this)"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-2x"></i></button>
          <button class="btn btn-delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDelete"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x"></i></button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sorted-row">
      <td>=</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="judul-bab">pasal 2</td>
      <td class="desc">merupakan isi untuk pasal yang berkaitan dengan aturan aturan perusahaan untuk pegawai dan ketetapan lainnya</td>
      <td>27 jan, 09:57am</td>
      <td>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <button class="btn btn-edit"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-2x"></i></button>
          <button class="btn btn-delete"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x"></i></button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">
        <button class="btn btn-add">tambah&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="saveChanges">
      <td colspan="6">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Simpan Perubahan</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

my expectation:
[image]

my result :
[image]

all i want :
[image]
thead and tbody column are straight position, being in one lane is not off the mark

Comment: Don't set width of td, add width on th according  to your need.

Comment: I've tried but it's still the same. not work for me

Answer (score 0):

You specified the width only for the `td.desc`.

`.table-contract th.desc { width: 50%; }`

Comment: i've already tried, but still doesn't worked for me

.table-contract thead th.desc,
.table-contract tbody td.desc {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
}

Comment: Removing `.table-contract tr{ display:table }` should work. Any reason you have set it to display as table?

Comment: i want tbody got scrolled.. cause that's my task.. but when it happened.. my thead and tbody are not in straight position.. so i asking this question

Comment: for that consider this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody)

Comment: it work with javascript.. thanks for refering the answer

Answer (score 0):

For alignment issues you can use css property **text-align: left**. You can set this css property with more values like left/center/right according to your requirement. I haved this css to below clas. Same like this you can add this property whereever it is required.

```
.table-contract td.desc {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Complete code below

```
table {
  font-size: medium;
}

.table-contract {
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px var(--uwongke-tertiary-color);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  empty-cells: show;
}

.table-contract thead th {
  background: var(--uwongke-tertiary-color);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px var(--uwongke-tertiary-color);
  color: var(--uwongke-light);
}

.table-contract thead th:first-child {
  background: var(--uwongke-tertiary-color);
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
}

.table-contract thead th:last-child {
  background: var(--uwongke-tertiary-color);
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}

.table-contract tr th,
.table-contract tr td {
  padding: 1.25rem;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.table-contract td.desc {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
}

.table-contract,
.table-contract th,
.table-contract td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}


/* .table-contract thead, */

.table-contract tbody {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table-contract tbody {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 50rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.table-contract tr {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Html code

```
<table class="table table-hover table-borderless text-center mb-0 table-contract">
  <thead class="text-capitalize">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="">&nbsp;</th>
      <th scope="col" class="">No</th>
      <th scope="col" class="">pasal</th>
      <th scope="col" class="desc">deskripsi</th>
      <th scope="col" class="">modifikasi</th>
      <th scope="col" class="">aksi</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="text-capitalize" id="table_drag">

    <tr class="sorted-row">
      <td>=</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="judul-bab">pasal 1</td>
      <td class="desc">merupakan isi untuk pasal yang berkaitan dengan aturan aturan perusahaan untuk pegawai dan ketetapan lainnya</td>
      <td>27 jan, 09:57am</td>
      <td>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <button class="btn btn-edit" onclick="edit(this)"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-2x"></i></button>
          <button class="btn btn-delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDelete"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x"></i></button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sorted-row">
      <td>=</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="judul-bab">pasal 2</td>
      <td class="desc">merupakan isi untuk pasal yang berkaitan dengan aturan aturan perusahaan untuk pegawai dan ketetapan lainnya</td>
      <td>27 jan, 09:57am</td>
      <td>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <button class="btn btn-edit"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-2x"></i></button>
          <button class="btn btn-delete"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x"></i></button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">
        <button class="btn btn-add">tambah&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="saveChanges">
      <td colspan="6">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Simpan Perubahan</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: still the same.. doesn't work on me. i mean.. tbody and th are in a straight position, not aiming at the paragraph of the text

Comment: I can see text is aligned left for tbody desc in this fiddle 

https://jsfiddle.net/zmduwv6x/

Comment: your jsfiddle is empty

Comment: Find updated fiddle here 
https://jsfiddle.net/Anjs_15/bste129j/

Comment: try check my updated question.. there's an image what i want.. sorry for not clearly question

Comment: You need to add width to all your columns and header to align them properly.

Comment: yes.. you are right, i already got what i want.. with javascript.. refer answer from pravesh