# HTML Table overflow-y scrolling with fixed y axis headings

Tags: javascript, html, css-tables

I have a table with headers for both the x and y axes, and want the table to scroll when it overflows on the y axis while retaining the header.

Using `display: block; overflow-y: auto;` in the `<table>` element gives me some scrolling, but I lose the y axis labels.

Here's a simple pen work-in-progress: https://codepen.io/Malgalin/pen/wNZRPz?editors=0100

I have also tried versions of making the `th[scope='row']` elements have a fixed position, which sort of works, but it creates messy over-lapping headers and makes the initial blank top left corner cell disappear.

I'm happy to see answers using JS or jQuery if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `sticky` position for your headers. You need to change your HTML a little bit, you need a wrapper for the table.

```
<div id='table_wrapper'>
  <table> .... </table>
</div>
```

Now you can set the TH elements to `position: sticky` and, for the thead, make it stick at `top: 0px`, for the tbody use `left: 0px`.

Using just that won't work on your actual code since you have some errors though. So, first close the thead tag and open a tbody tag properly (now you open the thead and close a tbody). The second thing you need to fix is to remove those `display:  block` on the table elements, when you do that you break the table.

Check this edited codepen link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/daLrGZ?editors=1100

Note that you'll need to add some background to the th's.

EDIT: if you want the top left TH to stay over the rest THs add this:

```
table thead tr th:first-child {
  left: 0px; //so it also sticks to the left
  z-index: 2; //so it's over the rest
}
```

Comment: Ah, apologies for the sloppy thead and tbody tags...some rookie copy-pasting from my work editor.  I'll have a look at your suggestion now.

Comment: This looks like it's most of the way there, but after setting the th elements to have opaque backgrounds, the top-left blank cell is still transparent. I tried a `&nbsp;` in there to trick it into treating it as having content, but still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Weird, I can set the background for all TH and the top left cell is not blank https://codepen.io/anon/pen/daLrGZ?editors=1100

Comment: Yeah, I see what it's doing. It is changing the color, but it treats the blank cell as movable instead of fixed, so when you scroll the username is visible above the header column...it's not a deal breaker though. I think I can work with that for now. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, perfect! Thanks. Shame I can't accept the answer twice :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you are looking is already solved, have a look and let me know:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50649696/5796090

In the link above you can find a scrollable table with a fixed header using CSS Grid.

Basically you define 2 areas in your grid for `thead` and `tbody` and set an overflow for the second one.

```
table {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "head-fixed" 
  "body-scrollable";
}

thead {
  grid-area: head-fixed;
}

tbody {
  grid-area: body-scrollable;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 400px; /* define height depending on your needs */
}
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: Hmm, I gave this a go, with some variations, with no luck. I'll maybe try implementing a version of this later though. I like the idea of a grid based approach. Thanks

Comment: It's simpler, declarative and you don't have to use a wrapper (avoid dividitis). You have a working example in the link above. Please, let me know if you struggle with something :)